# File object and java script

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do file upload in my project but i am facing this difficulty. when i run this i am getting "**access is denied**" script error when i am submitting to Server.jsp..

**Test.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
    <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
    <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>

    <iframe src = "fileselect.html" name = "attachfrm" width = 0 height=0></iframe>
    <a id = "att" href = "javascript:document.attachfrm.clickattach('compose');" >AttachFile</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

**FileSelect.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
    <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
    <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
    <title>Attach File</title>
    </HEAD>
    <script>
    function atach(){

    document.tattach.submit();
    }
    function clickattach(id){
    document.tattach.F1.click();
    }


    </script>
    <BODY>

    <FORM  ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION=
    "Server.jsp" METHOD=POST name="tattach">
    <br><br><br>
    <center><table border="2" >
    <tr><td><b>Choose the file To Upload:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
    <INPUT NAME="F1" id = "F1" TYPE="file" onChange="atach();"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">
    <p align="right">
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Attach"  >
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Cancel" onClick="window.close();">
    </p>
    </td></tr>

    <table>
    </center>      

    </FORM>

    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

**Server.jsp**

```
<%
System.out.println("------------got it-------------");
%>
```

**Note(another way that i got this to be working gud): But this works fine when i changed the FILE click like this in Test.html**

```
<a id = "att" href = "javascript:document.attachfrm.tattach.F1.click();" >AttachFile</a>
```

But i need to do my first method since i need to send the parameter from Test.html to FileSelect.html for some functionality.

Please correct me if i am wrong in my first method

Comment: You Can NOT automate the clicking of the `<input type="file"/>` button.  Security in all modern browsers forces the user to select a file vs. type in a path as well as open the file selection dialog via user interaction.

Comment: @scunliffe No we can the logic i found is <a id = "att" href = "javascript:document.attachfrm.tattach.F1.click();" >AttachFile</a> this work too gud

Comment: what is the "parameter" you are passing from the outer page to the inner iframe? (and are you attempting to alter/set the file being uploaded in any way shape or form?)  Typically the "access is denied" error appears whenever you are trying to do something you are not allowed/supposed to do... e.g calling .focus() on a DIV vs. an INPUT field.